# Updating MAC adtress table in switches

Tags: networking, arp, switching, ack

It's a theoretical question. Let's say I have a switch with 3 ports and 3 PCs with MAC address AA, BB, CC, and ports 1, 2, 3.

PC A wants to send a message to PC B so it sends an ARP request or a message with source AA and destination BB?

after that, B received a message from the switch, and then what it does? Send an ACK? Send a message back to the switch says I'm PC B so the switch will update its table?

Next stage, let's say the table contains all the MAC addresses of all PCs and PC B changes its port. PC A wants to send a message to PC B so the switch will forward it to port 2 but PC B won't be there. How to switch will know about this situation?

I know its basic but somehow I got messed with too much information

TIA

Comment: There is no such thing as 'received a message from the switch'. Switches don't originate messages, by definition: any messages come from the endpoints. They don't have tables either. Off topic.

Comment: Switches populate their MAC address tables from frames entering the switch. Every frame will update the MAC address table with the source MAC address and interface where the frame entered the switch. The entries in the table will time out (time depends on the switch model and configuration), and MAC destinations not in the table result in the frame being flooded to all other interfaces. In any case, this is not a programming question, so it is off-topic here. You should ask on the correct SE site.

Comment: OK thanks, I will ask somewhere else